# What method do I have to override to know when a fragment returns visible?

Tags: android, android-fragments

Suppose I have two fragments A and B with the same custom ActionBar.

1. A changes the title of the ActionBar (overriding onResume()):

   ```
   // This is the TextView of the title of my custom action bar.
   TextView tvTitle = . . .; 
   tvTitle.setText("FRAGMENT A);
   ```
2. A add B to the backstack;
3. B changes the title of the ActionBar (overriding onResume()):

   ```
   // This is the TextView of the title of my custom action bar.
   TextView tvTitle = . . .; 
   tvTitle.setText("FRAGMENT B);
   ```
4. The user press the back button and returns to the fragment A.
5. The fragment A has now the title of the fragment B.

How to avoid that?

Comment: override `onresume()` method of fragment A and set title again to title for Fragment A

Comment: Actually it's already in onResume()